# Remove selected value in combobox datasource

Tags: c#, combobox, datasource

I have a window form wherein the admin assigns a username and password to a certain employee. it has a combobox named cmboEmpName which contains the names of the employee.

when button new is click a messagebox will confirm the action. if yes is clicked, i want to remove the selected value on the combobox. But my code gives me an error..

```
Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.
```

Here is my code:

```
 if (MessageBox.Show("Are you want to add new record?", "Confirm New Record", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Record successfully added!");
                sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlcon.Close();
                cmboEmpName.Items.Remove(cmboEmpName.Items[cmboEmpName.SelectedIndex]);
                cmboEmpName.Refresh();

            }
```

Comment: You sould reomve the item from the `Datasource` not the `ComboBox`

Comment: How am i suppose to do that?

Comment: Remove it from the datasource and then rebind it with the combobox

Comment: can you give me a sample code because im a newbie in c#. thanks.

Comment: What is your comboBox datasource? List<T>, ObservableCollection<T>, Array, show your datasource code

Comment: i dont have my datasource code because i only set it on the combobox task when the combobox is clicked.

Comment: can you show the code that adds the items to the combobox, you must have a datasource or your combobox will be empty

Comment: i dont have the code because i set the datasource property of combobox on the COMBOBOX TASKS. (found on the design of the form, click the combobox and then an arrow pointing to the right will appear and that's it.)

Comment: DataTable table = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"Select EmpID, EmpFN + ' ' + EmpMN + ' ' + EmpLN as FullName from Employee", sqlcon);
            da.Fill(table);
            
            cmboEmpName.DataSource = new BindingSource(table, null);
            cmboEmpName.DisplayMember = "FullName";
            cmboEmpName.ValueMember = "EmpID";

Comment: here i just change my code.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is remove the item from the collection that you initially bind to the combobox. After that rebind to the combobox

Comment: how will i remove the item in the collection? i really don't have an idea because i only set the datasource of the combobox in its property not by code.

Answer (score 0):

What is the datasource property of cmboEmpName set to? You need to modify the underlying data structure. So if you have the datasource set to a `List<String>` object, then modify that object and then call DataBind on the combobox.

Comment: where can i find the datasource property?

Comment: its the object that you populated your combobox with.

Comment: hmmm. like the displaymember and the valuemember? if its the display member = employee name, valuemember = empID.

Comment: No, look at the properties of the combobox. The datasource is where the combobox gets the data it should display, the list of employees. What is that set to?

Comment: i get the data from a database.

Comment: DataTable table = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"Select EmpID, EmpFN + ' ' + EmpMN + ' ' + EmpLN as FullName from Employee", sqlcon);
            da.Fill(table);
            
            cmboEmpName.DataSource = new BindingSource(table, null);
            cmboEmpName.DisplayMember = "FullName";
            cmboEmpName.ValueMember = "EmpID";

Comment: After the `da.Fill(table);` line, try this: `var dataSrc = new BindingSource(table, null); cmboEmpName.DataSource = dataSrc;` Then you can do `dataSrc.RemoveAt(cmboEmpName.SelectedIndex);` You'll have to make sure the declaration for dataSrc is somewhere that makes it accessible from the code in your original question. Note that this won't delete from the database table.

Comment: it almost work but it gives me an error...

Index -1 is either negative or above rows count. because i declare this "cmboEmpName.SelectedIndex = -1;"